# application.html.erb overriding other html files

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, error-handling

I have a problem. My problem is that my application.html.erb file is overriding all other html files. Meaning when i try to show static#welcome only the html from my application html is showing. Started GET `"/" for ::1 at 2019-09-14 17:17:29 -0500
Processing by StaticController#welcome as HTML
  Rendering static/welcome.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered static/welcome.html.erb within layouts/application (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 28ms (Views: 24.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)`
 this is what shows in my terminal when I load the page.

````
 <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %><%= csrf_meta_tags %><%= csp_meta_tag %>
 </head>
 <body>    
   <title>Stufinder</title>
<p>listening to my heart instead of my head<p>
 </body> ```


this is my application.html.erb file

   <h1>howdy , welcome to my page.</h1>
this is my welcome page
````

Answer (score 0):

i fixed my problem by simply adding a equals sign in my application.html.erb file

`<%= yield %>`

Comment: that will do it. this is the centre of your applications html world

Answer (score 0):

Add `<%= yield %>` to make it work.
`Yield` is a key word in ruby. It will accept a block that is sent to method.